# Find a link in .NET WebBrowser

Tags: c#

I know this question has very little detail but I'll try and explain the best I can. I have scrolled all over good for a solution but I can't find a single one. I haven't tried anything because I don't really know where to start?

Okay, I want to find the href of this link and direct my browser to it programatically. Is that possible? When redirecting them to just /sign-out it doesn't work due to the token issue.

Finding a link in C# WebBrowser?

```
<li><a href="/sign-out?t=e8fd9b802946bfe81a9c51961b8a62b3"><i class="ico-signout mr5"></i>Sign Out</a></li>
```

Comment: webclient with regex?

Comment: How can I identify that specific link if there are multiple?

Comment: this is not matter if they are the same they will redirect to the same place...

Comment: What distinguishes the specific link you are after?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can get the source from most web browser controls, so just do that then use a html parser

Comment: @Sayse: WebBrowser is a control specific to .NET, using Internet Explorer as its underlying engine.

Comment: do you have control of the HTML/javascript as well as the C# engine?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey: Manipulating Javascript in these things is a bit problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get from the web browser the content of the site, use regex to find the href using this pattern

```
public ArrayList HRefs(string incomingHtml)
{
  ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
  string pattern = "href\\s*=\\s*(?:\"(?<1>[^\"]*)\"|(?<1>\\S+))";
  for (Match match = Regex.Match(incomingHtml, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled); match.Success; match = match.NextMatch())
  {
    string str = match.Groups[1].Value;
    arrayList.Add((object) str);
  }
  return arrayList;
}
```

Comment: OK.  And then ..?

Comment: webBrowser1.Navigate to any link in the array

Comment: But how would I find the link I need?

Comment: you will get all the href's in the html, search the one contains sign-out

Comment: @SerioskOfficial: All of the links are in the `ArrayList` returned by his function.  Look through those and decide which one you want to navigate to.

Comment: I've managed to do what I want to do by looping through and checking if it starts with "/sign-out", thank you.

Comment: you can upgrade the regex pattern so it will be more specific for what you looking for

Answer (score 2):

So there are a lot of ways to do this but specifically with the WebBrowser control you can get the element by it's class name.

So in your webbrowser document loaded method try:

```
    var links = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("i");
    foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
    {
        if (link.GetAttribute("className") == "mr5")
        {
            var href = link.innerHtml;
        }
    }
```

Comment: regex is a bit messy, here is a very adaptable way.

Comment: I actually prefer this solution.  I suppose you could even use a Linq method to get the one you want.

Comment: regex is much faster... :)

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot.